# Nested Enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

How can I create the following format?

i. Header 1

```
I. Ex 1 to be used later in the text
```

ii. Header 2

```
II. Ex 2 to be used later in the text
```

iii. Header 3

```
III. Ex 3 to be used later in the text
```

Hope this help. [Image of what I am looking for](https://ibb.co/bLZSJz)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please show us what you have tried so far as minimal compilable code example (MWE)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Are we really talking about an `enumerate` here, or rather about a section-like heading or more something like a `theorem`/`definition` environment. Maybe you can explain what you want to do in more detail, if it helps you can also add a picture mockup of what you have in mind.

Comment: @user168001 Please check the updated answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps (under the assumption that you are trying to create a continuous list of enumerated which are nested, based on your example).

By invoking `enumitem` package and using `resume` option, you can achieve what you (might) want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item a
\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \end{enumerate}  
\item b
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which gives you

[image]

You can play with the type of counters to change their apperance :)

As OP requested,

Update in MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
     \begin{enumerate}[i.]
         \item afd
         \begin{enumerate}[I] 
            \item mv
        \end{enumerate} 
        \item jh
        \begin{enumerate}[resume*] 
            \item lgh
        \end{enumerate} 
    \item lkgh
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*]
        \item 
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

to get: (not able to upload the images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtFmH.jpg

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. I was using 'resume' instead of 'resume*'.

Comment: @user168001 Great! you are welcome, and if you find the answer helpful, consider accepting it :)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to remove the first part because it has errors.

Comment: @user168001 atleast I dont see any errors, could you tell me what errors you see when you compile?

Comment: It is fine. My mistake. 
Only if I add a specific counter style then it shows compilation error.